# Custom Date validation Format

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Using C#

C# Code

```
protected void cusCustom_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Value.Length == 8)
        e.IsValid = true;
    else
        e.IsValid = false;
}
```

Page code

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" id="cusCustom" controltovalidate="txtoedate" onservervalidate="cusCustom_ServerValidate" errormessage="The text must be exactly 8 characters long!" />
```

The above code is working for the length, but i want to check the date format like this
"yyyy-mm-dd", for checking this date format, how to change my code.

Need Code Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, firstly, your date format isn't 8 characters long, so you'll need to fix that to 10. Then your best bet is a `DateTime.TryParseExact` with the specific format you want to validate.

```
DateTime value;
e.IsValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(e.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out value);
```

You can get away with InvariantCulture because you are only dealing with the numeric representations of the date parts and are specifying the format exactly.

Comment: Oh no, please don't do `try...catch` for validating dates. Use `DateTime.TryParseExact`.

Comment: @Darin - how did I know about `TryParse` but not `TryParseExact`? Thanks.

Comment: @Gopal - in the answer (in case you didn't notice already...)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DateTime.TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) .

Comment: A sample was in the link I provided, I guess it was not visible enough, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

try regular expression for date